# Google Search that Returns XML

Tags: xml, web-services

I want to do a Google search that returns an XML document (instead of html). Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [Google AJAX Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/)

Answer (score 1):

I use the Google Custom Site Search. You can have it return XML.
See: http://www.google.com/cse/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the

> filetype

dork like: filetype:xml